# I want to fry meat but I don't have oil, unfortunately there's no near store in my location

Tags: food

Is there something that I can do if I ran out of oil and I wanted to fry some meat?

Assuming that:

1. The only food that I have is meat.
2. There's no near store in my current location

Comment: This is one for http://cooking.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Trim a little of the fat off the edge of the cut of meat and put that in the hot pan first.  Wipe it around to lubricate the pan, then put the meat in to fry.  If you don't have a knife handy, you could even just rub the fatty edge of the cut on the pan surface (though good luck eating the meat without a knife, unless it's a top quality cut).

Comment: If the meat isn't fat you may have some bacon or other fatty meat handy.

Answer (score 1):

You could use butter or coconut oil if you have some. If not, use your oven to cook your meat.

Comment: What I want is to fry, not just to cook. And as I have mentioned already the store isn't available.